# Set default item selected in MMDrawerController

Tags: ios, ios7, mmdrawercontroller

I use the MMDrawerController library to create a drawer menu. Everything works fine but when the app start and my default view is displayed, the corresponding item is not selected.

Is there a way to force an item in selected status the same way it is when user select one from the menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually resolved this problem by forcing the selected item on the table view, not on the instance of the MMDrawerController object. Works like a charm !